# Can someone show me a simple example of strategy pattern using scheme?

Tags: design-patterns, scheme, strategy-pattern

I am new to design pattern and I am trying to learn the strategy pattern. After reading bunch examples here and on oodesign.com, I have a fair understanding of  its intent. However, most  example I found are in Java, C# or, C/C++; these languages are more structured and force you to have class and such. When it comes to dynamic language like scheme, I have trouble picturing how I could implement such pattern. Could someone show me a example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could draw up a more complex example, although there are already great built-in methods native to the language that demonstrate the strategy pattern. This implements the strategy pattern with scheme's first-class functions:

```
(define (calculate-bonuses lst double?)
   (define (triple x) (* x 3))
   (define (double x) (* x 2))

   (map (if double? double triple) lst))

(calculate-bonuses '(1200 3250 4000 890) #t)
(calculate-bonuses '(1200 3250 4000 890) #f)
```

We process/manipulate the same data, although each time with a different strategy. This is a toy example, so the strategy selection here isn't very advanced, although by the same token it could be a list, or a lookup table of sorts.

Answer (score 9):

In Scheme and Racket, the strategy pattern is ... wait for it ... function application.

The Wikipedia page for strategy gives this example of using it:

```
//StrategyExample test application

class StrategyExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Context context;

      // Three contexts following different strategies
      context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyAdd());
      int resultA = context.executeStrategy(3,4);

      context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategySubtract());
      int resultB = context.executeStrategy(3,4);

      context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyMultiply());
      int resultC = context.executeStrategy(3,4);
  }
}
```

In Scheme or Racket, you'd just write this as:

```
(+ 3 4)
(- 3 4)
(* 3 4)
```

And, if you wanted to pass a strategy to be applied to a set of arguments, it might look like this:

```
#lang racket
(define (apply-strategy strategy context)
  (strategy context))
```

Really, the only major reason for the existence of the Strategy pattern is the weakness of Java's type system.

Comment: +1 This man speaks the truth. Also, for more lulz: `(require srfi/26) (define apply-strategy (cut <> <>))`